# How would I be able to make this possible with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, backup, share, windows-server

Basically what I want to do is locate a shared folder on the server (I'll be running this script from the domain controller), unshare it (so I make sure no user is still using files from there, to avoid issues), and then backup all the files from that folder into a .zip/.rar, then share the folder again. I been looking into how to automate this using powershell (I dont have much experience with it), I found this script (https://github.com/Seidlm/PowerShell-Backup-Script/blob/master/BackupScript.ps1) that im planning to modify, but I still not know how to unshare and share a folder with powershell or how to make it so that the script is automatically executed for example every day at 1:00 am or something like that, how would I be able to this? I dont want you guys to do my homework, if you could just point me in the right direction or link some documentation I would apreciate it.

Comment: For the scheduled execution, look at how to set up tasks in the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Check out the [SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/?view=win10-ps) module or the [Win32_Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-share) WMI class.